# How to use MPMediaPickerController with Local Files in Documents Directory?

Tags: ios, open-source, media-player

I want to be able to use the MPMediaPickerController on local files that were downloaded in the Documents directory.
However, there is no option to set the source of the files that the controller looks in, which defaults of course to the iPod music library.

Are there any methods to load local files, or any alternate libraries available to provide the media picking functionality? Or will I have to reinvent the wheel here :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [AVAudioPlayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) instead, seeing as MPMediaPickerController is a class designed to play music stored only in the iTunes media folder.  It's also very easy to play media with from the doc directory:

```
NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mySong.m4a"];
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:soundFilePath];
NSError *error;
AVAudioPlayer* audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:&error];
if(!error){
    audioPlayer.delegate = self;
    [audioPlayer play];
}else{
    NSLog(@"Error loading clip: %@", [error localizedDescription]); 
}
```

Comment: You'll need to make your own UI for browsing/choosing files, though.

Comment: Thanks, I went with an open-source music player that is based on AVAudioPlayer!